# Exclude the tag string when using adb logcat in CMD

Tags: cmd, adb, logcat, android-logcat

When using adb logcat in CMD, is there a way to have the log only show the String I am writing to the log, and not the tag along with random numbers?  Right now, for example, it says:

"D/MainActivity(  970): myString"

I just want it to say myString, where myString is whatever I wanted to log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log record format is fixed. Every record saved to the log will include all the fields. But you can control which fields get printed out:

```
-v <format>     Sets the log print format, where <format> is:
--format=<format>
                  brief color epoch long monotonic printable process raw
                  tag thread threadtime time uid usec UTC year zone
```

`raw` is the format you are looking for

```
adb logcat -v raw
```

Comment: Great!  A follow up question... I am also filtering using `adb logcat -s "MainActivity"` but when I type that in or `adb logcat -v raw` like you said, it won't let me type anything else since the log is going.  Is there a way to write both of those at once before the log starts?

Comment: yes. you can combine the parameters. but sometimes the order matters

Comment: Oh, I see you can just type them one after another.  I didn't think that would work for some reason.  Thanks!